# How to interactively select and blur a rectangular zone of an image using pyqt4?

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, image-processing, pyqt

I am using pyqt4 to develop an interface that shows an image and allows the user to select a rectangular zone in order to blur it.

I am showing a QPixmap image using QtGui.QGraphicsPixmapItem, and I managed to trigger the mousePressEvent, mouseMoveEvent and mouseReleaseEvent.

I am not able now to discover how to use these events in order to select a rectangular zone in the image and blur it once the user release the mouse.

The following step is to save the blurred image back to the disk.

Any help is highly appreciated.
Rami

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were you, I'd work with the image in memory, and show the updates if there is a change:

1. read the image using the Python Imaging library (PIL).
2. show the image using Qt
3. react to mouse events, process the image in memory, and update screen

PIL makes it easy to filter (eg. blur) the image: http://effbot.org/imagingbook/imagefilter.htm